# fwrite not working with some additional non-special characters

Tags: php, fwrite

I have a script to send post to an url. The complete code doesn't work for the following example, it does not show any error

```
<?php
$posturl = 'https://sub1.domain.com/mailforward.php';
$message_array = array();
$message_array['From'] = 'WordPress <wordpress@sub2.domain.com>';
$message_array['To'] = 'me@domain.com';
$message_array['Subject'] = '[My Blog] Password Reset';

$message_array['Body'] = 'Someone has requested a password reset for the following account:

https://sub2.domain.com/dir/

Username: admin

If this was a mistake, just ignore this email and nothing will happen.

To reset your password, visit the following address:

<https://sub2.domain.com/dir/wp-login.php>';

post_async($posturl,$message_array);

function post_async($url, $params)
{
// Build POST string
foreach ($params as $key => &$val) {
  if (is_array($val)) $val = implode(',', $val);
  $post_params[] = $key.'='.urlencode($val);
}
$post_string = implode('&', $post_params);

// Connect to server
$parts=parse_url($url);
$fp = fsockopen($parts['host'],isset($parts['port'])?$parts['port']:80,$errno, $errstr, 30);

// Build HTTP query             
$out = "POST ".$parts['path']." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$out.= "Host: ".$parts['host']."\r\n";
$out.= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$out.= "Content-Length: ".strlen($post_string)."\r\n";
$out.= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
$out.= $post_string;

// Send data and close the connection
fwrite($fp, $out);
fclose($fp);
}

?>
```

However, if in the variable `$message_array['Body']`, if I remove `.php` in the last line (That is, to replace `wp-login.php` with `wp-login`), the script works as expected.

I'm very surprised about this, since `.php` does not contain any special character.

Comment: I have found the problem. That is because the server has a firewall rule that block if post data contains `wp-login.php` string.

Answer (score 0):

Its now showing error possible because php error reporting is off on your server. 
At least it shows you error on this line where you are calling the function before its declaration.

```
post_async($posturl,$message_array);
```

You should turn on errors on your server so that you can come to know what problem you are facing. Also, you have to call the function after its declaration. Just like given below...

```
function post_async($url, $params)
{
// Build POST string
foreach ($params as $key => &$val) {
  if (is_array($val)) $val = implode(',', $val);
  $post_params[] = $key.'='.urlencode($val);
}

post_async($posturl,$message_array);
```

Comment: It doesn't matter where you declare the function, either at the top or the bottom of the script. I have enabled `error_reporting = E_ALL` (followed by apache2 restart), it still shows no error.